# Largest and smallest integer - exercise from Deitel's Java book

Tags: java

Exercise from Deitel's "Java How To Program" 10th edition:

> 2.24 (Largest and Smallest Integers) Write an application that reads five integers and determines and prints the largest and smallest
>   integers in the group. Use only the programming techniques you learned
>   in this chapter.

My code:

```
// Ex. 2.24: LargestAndSmallestIntegers.java
// Obtain five numbers from the user, display largest and smallest from the group.
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LargestAndSmallestIntegers
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number1, 
            number2, 
            number3, 
            number4, 
            number5,
            largest,
            smallest;

        System.out.print("Enter first integer: ");
        number1 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter second integer: ");
        number2 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter third integer: ");
        number3 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter fourth integer: ");
        number4 = input.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter fifth integer: ");
        number5 = input.nextInt();

        largest = number1;
        smallest = number1;

        if (number2 > largest)
            largest = number2;
        if (number3 > largest)
            largest = number3;
        if (number4 > largest)
            largest = number4;
        if (number5 > largest)
            largest = number5;

        if (number2 < smallest)
            largest = number2;
        if (number3 < smallest)
            largest = number3;
        if (number4 < smallest)
            largest = number4;
        if (number5 < smallest)
            largest = number5;

        System.out.printf("Largest of five integers is %d, and smallest is %d%n", largest, smallest);
    }
}
```

What did I do wrong? Why it doesn't pick-up the largest and smallest integers?

Comment: Carefully look at what your program is doing: `if (number2 < smallest) largest = number2;` do you see the mistake?

Comment: <facepalm/> That will teach me to not mindlessly copy&paste code without paying attention to details. Thanks!

Comment: An aside, without knowing what you "have learned in this chapter": Now, generalize this to read an *arbitrary* number of integers. (Maybe at least a motiviation for one of the next chapters...)

Comment: what the point of "exercise" if you ask other people what the problem is? you should figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second block you check with `smallest` and assign to `largest`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess copy paste typo error. For section calculating smallest, replace all largest to smallest as largest value obtained from list is overwritten with smallest values from remaining conditions.

```
    largest = number1;
    smallest = number1;

    if (number2 > largest)
        largest = number2;
    if (number3 > largest)
        largest = number3;
    if (number4 > largest)
        largest = number4;
    if (number5 > largest)
        largest = number5;

    // Error here 
    // fixed typos
    if (number2 < smallest)
        smallest = number2;
    if (number3 < smallest)
        smallest = number3;
    if (number4 < smallest)
        smallest = number4;
    if (number5 < smallest)
        smallest = number5;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if ( two > largest ){
        largest = two;
        System.out.printf ( "Largest of five values is %d, and the smallest is %d%n", largest, smallest );
    }
    else if ( three > largest ){
        largest = three;
        System.out.printf ( "Largest of five values is %d, and the smallest is %d%n", largest, smallest );
    }
    else if ( four > largest ){
        largest = four;
        System.out.printf ( "Largest of five values is %d, and the smallest is %d%n", largest, smallest );
    }
    else if ( five > largest ){    
        largest = five;
        System.out.printf ( "Largest of five values is %d, and the smallest is %d%n", largest, smallest );
    }


    if ( two < smallest ){
        smallest = two;
        System.out.printf ( "Largest of five values is %d, and the smallest is %d%n", largest, smallest );
    }
    else if ( three < smallest ){
        smallest = three;
        System.out.printf ( "Largest of five values is %d, and the smallest is %d%n", largest, smallest );
    }
    else if ( four < smallest ){
        smallest = four;
        System.out.printf ( "Largest of five values is %d, and the smallest is %d%n", largest, smallest );
    }
    else if ( five < smallest ){    
        smallest = five;
        System.out.printf ( "Largest of five values is %d, and the smallest is %d%n", largest, smallest );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class LargestSmallest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Declare class variables
        int counter = 0;
        int number = 0;
        int largest = 0;
        int smallest = 0;

        while (counter < 5) {
            counter++;
            System.out.println("Enter the number");
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            number = sc.nextInt();

            if (number > largest) {
                largest = number;
            } else if (number < largest) {
                smallest = number;
            }

            // Display Largest and Smallest
            System.out.println("largest number is: " + largest);
            System.out.println("smallest number is: " + smallest);
        }
    }
}
```